# VB - Writing to a file with StreamWriter

Tags: vb.net, debugging, streamwriter, file-in-use

I'm trying to write to a file using the StreamWriter.

```
Dim write as IO.StreamWriter
write = new io.streamwriter(file)
write.write(txtEncryption.text)
write.close
```

I stopped the code in debug mode and i saw it crashes and goes straight to the exception when reaches line 2.

It is because i just made the file and it's still in use ? How can i avoid that ?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Well essentially you have to chatch the IOException if the file is still in use, and tell the User to close all programs that have access to the file and try again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dim write As  IO.StreamWriter 
Try 
  write=New IO.StreamWriter(file)  
  write.write(txtEncryption.text)

Catch ex As Exception
  'Prompt error
  Console.WriteLine("Error {0}",ex.Message)

Finally 
    If write IsNot Nothing Then
        write.Close() 
    End If
End Try
```

Assumption (if file was not opened anywhere else) : You open already opened one.Make sure that all your opened streams closed properly. You can use this syntax too

```
Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(file)
        writer.Write("....")
           //and so on
End Using
```

Comment: @user3246386 I posted code that will handle error. Probably you open file but without closing you try to open again. So use using to handle close per open properly

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim FileLic As New System.IO.StreamWriter("Licenseaccepted", False)

        '("Licenseaccepted", False)
        FileLic.WriteLine(lblLICaccept.Text)
        FileLic.WriteLine(AuthorYear)
        FileLic.WriteLine("Non cancellare o modificare questo file.")
        FileLic.Close()
```

This solution worked correctly for me.