# Writing to a new line in Visual Basic with Streamwriter

Tags: vb.net, newline, streamwriter, streamwriter.write

Every time I press "button2" it **should** take the data from various text boxes and write them into my text file on a new line. For some unknown reason, the program just overwrites everything in the text file, whereas I need it to write to a new line. If someone knows how to do this please let me know!

Refer the below Code:

```
Public Class Form5
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Hide()
    Form2.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim username As String = (TextBox1.Text & TextBox2.Text)
    Dim password As String = "password"
    Dim forename As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim surname As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim dob As String = TextBox3.Text
    Dim phone As String = TextBox4.Text
    Dim address As String = TextBox5.Text
    Dim filename As String = "../../usernamepassword.txt"
    Dim objreader As New System.IO.StreamWriter(filename)
    objreader.WriteLine(username & "," & password & "," & forename & "," & surname & "," & dob & "," & phone & "," & address & ",")
    objreader.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: @Refer this URL : [How to: Write Text to Files with a StreamWriter in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxwfzt61.aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB - Writing to a file with StreamWriter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455612/vb-writing-to-a-file-with-streamwriter)

Answer (score 1):

You need to append text, and by using the `Using` statement, it takes care of the disposal of the object, allowing the object to cleanly terminate its resources, which I recommend you use.

```
Using sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(filename)
  sw.WriteLine(username & "," & password & "," & forename & "," & surname & "," & dob & "," & phone & "," & address & ",")
End Using
```

---

I also changed the variable `objreader` to something more relative to what it is doing, again I recommend you do like that to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**`StreamWriter(String, Boolean)` constructor**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx) to specify whether you want to append to or overwrite the file.

Preferrably also wrap your `StreamWriter` in a [**`Using` block**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) instead of calling `Close()`.

```
Using objreader As New System.IO.StreamWriter(filename, True) 'True = append.
    objreader.WriteLine(username & "," & password & "," & forename & "," & surname & "," & dob & "," & phone & "," & address & ",")
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this code works! Would there be any way to have the new data written onto a new line in the text file, instead of just at the end of the old one. thanks

Comment: @AlfieF : If you're always using `WriteLine` then that should be take care of for you. If it isn't done automatically for some reason then you can try prepending it with a new line like so: `objreader.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine & username & ...`